# how to fill blank space with white to my pasted images?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, margin

I'm using Python pillow to attach several pictures.
When the attached picture is 1100x5000px,
I want to fill in the blank space with a white screen.
And I don't want the picture to shrink or cut automatically.

[image: problem]

I saw this post and modified some part.
https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-concat-images/

Now, I'm adjusting one white image to resize and filling the empty space.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZAxX.png)

It works anyway. But I think this method is too inefficient, so I want to know another way.

I searched about margin and numpy method. But not worked.
In the process of combining, the picture was cut or the size of the picture was adjusted.

If the design changes or I need to add more pictures,
I would like to automatically fill in the appropriate margins.

Comment: Hello, please do not post images of your code. You should include those as text formatted in code blocks. Also, instead of opening a blank image and resizing, how about you just create blank images of whatever size you need? Use [Image.new](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new), or simply make a numpy array of the desired size (`np.full((H, W, 3), 255, np.uint8)`).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please click [edit] and try to improve your question. It is hard to understand what you actually start with and what you want to get. Also please add your code. Thanks.